# double pointer to constant pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

hey can some one tells me why in this example the value 11 11 will appear ,if i unterstand this correctly 
the p in main block is constant pointer to an Integer which means i cant change the value of its adress
how come that i could do that in the fuction foo through

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int j = 11;
void foo(int **);

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *const p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
void foo(int **p)
{
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

Comment: Please don't update your question to solve problems from posted answers. That could make the answers useless, and sometimes even your question might become useless if you solve all the problems. Remember that this forum isn't just to solve your problem you you right here and now, but also for other people to find solutions to similar (or exactly the same) problems in the future.

Comment: This code isn't valid C, so what it will do if some compiler let it through regardless is anyone's guess. You simply can't implicitly convert from `int*const*` to `int**`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the original code contained several errors that were unrelated to question being asked. See my explanation of the change. The edits do require peer review before they are accepted. My edit was accepted so that answers could focus on the concept of discarded qualifiers, rather than the idiosyncrasies of his particular snippet.

Comment: @Lundin try having clang or gcc compile exactly the code snippet above. It works fine, but they both give discarded qualifier warnings. The resultant executable prints `"11\n11\n"` for both.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom There is no such thing as "compiler errors" in the C language, that's why. A compiler is only obliged to give a diagnostic message upon C language violations. If the compiler chose to do that through a warning, error or a handwritten note delivered to the programmer's doorstep isn't the C standard's business. Still it is a constraint violation of the language standard. If you wish gcc or clang to give you compiler errors for C language violations, you must compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @Lundin as a counterexample, the compiler would produce an error if foo required two arguments. That would be a non-pedantic syntax error.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom A constraint violation isn't "less wrong" than a syntax error. Otherwise I would be able to write `int x; y: ... if(y) goto x;` and that would be "correct" C. What gcc calls "pedantic" isn't actually pedantic, but rather the actual C language, with all non-standard GNU extensions removed. The people who've developed gcc over the years have a fondness for weird extensions and therefore like to promote those as the normal state of affairs. And other newer compilers like clang simply copy cat all gcc options for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Lundin Then it appears I have fallen for some GNU propaganda

Answer (score 1):

You have *undefined behavior*.

First your function `foo` attempt to modify the `main` variable `p`, which is *constant*. If you provided a proper function declaration/prototype of `foo` before calling it, the compiler would have been able to catch this and warn you about passing incompatible types.

*Furthermore* in `foo` you have the assignment

```
*p = &j;
```

With that you make `*p` point to the *local* variable `j`, a variables whose life-time ends when the `foo` function ends, making the pointer invalid when you dereference it in the `main` function.

Comment: The question has been updated to move the declaration of `j` to global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers, including clang and gcc, will react to your snippet with a warning that goes something like this.

> **Passing `const int *` as `int *` argument discards qualifiers**

This means that the compilers sees that you’re violating the constancy of the pointer. Despite complaining, compilers will try to compensate. The compiler will ignore the `const` modifier in your declaration of `p`. **The *effective* type of `p` at runtime will be that of a mutable `int *`.**

This behavior is not part of any C standard. Strictly speaking, `const` is like a promise you make to the compiler that you won’t modify something. This promise allows certain optimizations in machine code, by allowing the compiler to assume certain values will never change. **When you craftily violate the `const` promise through implicit type <del>casting</del> conversion, more naive (but still technically compliant) compiler might produce machine code that runs into segmentation faults or other problems, because you betray the assumption of constancy.**

Modern compilers always check whether `const` things are really constant. If they aren’t then the compilers “discard qualifiers”, meaning they infer that you didn’t really mean to say `const`. Most compilers also infer that you *did* mean `const` if you never change a variable’s value, regardless of whether you declared it constant.

#### Further Reading

- [Great summary of this conundrum in general](https://matt.sh/sytycc)
- [Clang 11 documentation of the associated warning](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers)
- [GCC documentation of the associated warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#error:_passing_.27const_X.27_as_.27this.27_argument_discards_qualifiers_.5B-fpermissive.5D)

Comment: "a more naive (but still technically compliant)" Not true. A compiler that doesn't give a diagnostic message for this is not compliant. It's a constraint violation of the simple assignment rules. This has always been the case since 1989.

Comment: Also there is nothing called "implicit type casting". There is implicit or explicit _conversions_. A cast is an explicit conversion.

Comment: @Lundin I didn’t know that casting was only explicit. That’s interesting. I have corrected the term. I am now looking up the simple assignment rules to verify your first comment.

Comment: 6.5.16.1 "... and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualiﬁers of the type pointed to by the right;". Parameter passing to functions is carried out after the rules of simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When passing `p` to `foo` the `const` qualifier of your pointer gets discarded because the function parameter is of type `int **`

With proper warnings enabled your compiler should have thrown the warning:

> passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

So you should change `foo` to:
`void foo (int * const * p)`
then your compiler will abort with the error

> assignment of read-only location

The problem of assigning the address of a local variable which runs out of scope was already pointed out by the others

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior.

For starters the function `f` should be declared before its call in main.

In this case the compiler will issue an error saying that the qualifier const of the argument was discarded.

Changing a constant object (in this case a constant pointer) through a pointer results in undefined behavior.

The second reason of the undefined behavior is that the variable `j` is a local variable of the function `f`. So after exiting the function the variable is not alive any more and the pointer `p` has an invalid value.

If you will write the function correctly declaring it before its call in main like for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *const *p )
{
    int j = 11;

    *p = &j;

    printf( "**p = %d\n", **p );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 10;

    int * const p = &i;

    f( &p );

    printf( "*p = %d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

you will get an error message similar to the following

```
prog.c: In function ‘f’:
prog.c:7:5: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*p’
  *p = &j;
     ^
```